# What is the best way to find the max record of a table per a foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

At work, I often have to find the max status per a foreign key. I have for the most part always used a correlated sub-query on the join to get the right record. This is assuming the highest primary key is the most recent. Here is a little demo

```
select 
    c.plate_number, o.name
from
    Car c
    inner join Owner o
        on o.owner_id = (
            select max(owner_id)
            from Owner
            where owner_type = 'PRIMARY'
        )
```

This is pretty fast in most queries I use, not to mention being able to put extra criteria in the sub-query for type columns. I have tried using NOT EXIST clauses to make sure there are no higher records, but can't find anything else. Can someone suggest anything better and if so why?

Comment: What is the relationship between Car and Owner tables?

Comment: If you want most recent records, use a datetime field.  Then you don't have to make assumptions.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that the query returns only one row?

Comment: @shree.pat18 One to many relationship.

Comment: @AlexanderFedorenko The most recent row per record in the parent table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the sandard windowing functions....

```
;with cte as (
    select c.plateNumber, o.name, 
           row_number() over (partition by c.ownerId order by  purchaseDate desc) rw
    from car c
        inner join owner o
          on o.ownerid = c.ownerid
 )
 select * 
 from cte
 where rw=1;
```

allows you to get whatever you want from either table, and still only get one record

Comment: I should have been more clear with my question. I want to get the most recent child record per parent record in a one to many relationship.

Comment: That is exactly what this allows you to do.  Just put the extra columns that you desire into the select with the row count, and have the order by be whatever column you use to define "recent".  Without a full column list, I assumed that there is a "purchased" column, but it could be lastupdated, id, whatever you use.

Comment: I typically just use the PK as that has been the standard that the highest record is the latest. But getting back to the main point, what is better about your version using the windowing/ ranking function?

Comment: It's better because it is not a correlated subquery.  I believe it also gives the query optimizer a better chance of speeding things up as it describes what you want a bit better.

Comment: Even though it is being used with a CTE? I thought CTEs were painfully slow for non-recursive tasks.

Comment: Of themselves, cte's cause no performance hit. Like views, they get rewritten by they optimizer at will.